# Align two images of different sizes next to each other in HTML table for email

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

How do I align two images of different size next right to each other? The larger image on the right is pushing the image on the left down to the middle. They should be right next to each other and then text will appear under the left image. This is for an email template. I tried `display:inline-block` and that did not work.

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td width="10" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#aaaaaa">Test</font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="290" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#aaaaaa"><img src="http://placehold.it/248x59" alt="!"></font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#aaaaaa">Test</font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="280" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#aaaaaa"><img src="http://placehold.it/226x350" alt="!"></font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#aaaaaa">Test</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
           </table>
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qb6nf2u0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the vertical placement? Not sure what you mean by right "next" to each other. You can control the vertical placement using `valign="top"` attribute. As for the text there is no way the text will show up under with the current html.

Comment: Yes I did meant vertical placement. Your answer is correct and worked perfectly! Thank you very much!  The text is being placed in the same cell as the smaller image so its fine.